# Write a C Program to extract a portion of a string from a character string using for loop

Tags: c, string, for-loop, character, extract

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
char str1[50],str2[50];
int i,j,n,m,l;
clrscr();
printf("Enter the string\n");
gets(str1); //scanf ("%s",str1);
printf("Enter the position of the required character: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Enter the required number of characters to be extracted: ");
scanf("%d",&m);
l=strlen(str1);
if(m+n-1<l)
 {
  for(i=n-1;i<m+n-1;i++)
   {
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
     str2[j]=str1[i];
     str2[j]='\0';
    }
   }
printf ("The extracted string is: %s",str2);
 }
else
printf ("string extraction is not possible");
}
```

Expected Output

```
Enter the string : UNIVERSITY IN BANGALORE

Enter the position of the required character: 6

Enter the required number of characters to be extracted: 4

The extracted string is: SITY
```

Comment: did you tryed to use strncpy?

Comment: And your question is? (Okay, you're not getting the desired output, because you overwrite the copied character `str2[j]` with the null terminator immediately instead of after the loop. You also don't need two nested loops; `i` and `j` are related through the offset, i.e the starting position.)

Answer (score 1):

```
package exatractstring;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class ExatractString {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str;
        int begin,end;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a String : ");
        str = s.nextLine();
        int sizeString  = str.length();

        System.out.println("Enter Extract Begining Position : ");
        begin = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Extract end Position : ");
        end = sc.nextInt();
        if(begin < 0 || end>sizeString )
        {
            System.out.println("You are wrong ..!!!");
        }
        System.out.println(str.substring(begin,end));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when the number of extracted characters exceeds the number of available characters of the source string starting from the given position  then all the available characters are copied.

I would write the main loop the following way

```
if ( n < l )
{
    i = 0;
    for ( ; i < m && str1[n + i] != '\0'; i++  )
    {
        str2[i] = str1[n + i];
    }
    str2[i] = '\0';

    printf( "The extracted string is: %s\n", str2 );
}
else
{
    puts( "string extraction is not possible" );
}
```

Take into account that function main shall have return type `int`.

```
int main()
```

Also it would be much better if all these variables, n, m, l, i would be declared as having type `size_t` instead of int. Otherwise you should check whether their values are negative.:)

Comment: It should be str1[n+i-1] I guess.(while copying)

Comment: @Sanjeev Hegde  No, it should not. According to the example of the input position starts with 0.